# Парсинг XML по атрибуту тега

Tags: xml, php, синтаксический-анализ

Есть XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<billboard>
    <films>
        <film id="120">
            <title orig="101 Dalmatians">101 долматинец</title>
            <duration>0</duration>
            <year>1996</year>
            <age_limit>0</age_limit>
            <budget currency="usd">0</budget>
            <intro>
                <![CDATA[Круэлла Де Вит владеет богатой коллекцией мехов. Они являются ее страстью, и заставляют совершать ужасные поступки, например, убийство. Ее коварный план близок к осуществлению. Жертвами коварной дамы оказываются беззащитные животные. .]]>
            </intro>
        </film>
    </films>
</billboard>
</xml>
```

Как спарсить и вывести все по тегу film, который имеет id="120"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$x = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr); // код вашей xml-ки
var_dump($x->xpath("//film[@id=120]"));
```

Comment: А как вывести на экран по тегам ?(title,year,... ) (Я новичёк)var_dump это переменная содержащая массив ?

Comment: Для начала вам нужно ознакомиться с основами пшп. var_dump - это функция, возвращающая представление переменной в удобной для прочтения форме.

Дальше будет что-то типа:

   echo "Title: ".$film->title;

и так далее