# Парсинг XML

Tags: xml, php, синтаксический-анализ

Есть xml файл test.xml, в котором содержится:

```
<merchant.response>
<operation wmtransid="782312540" wminvoiceid="336870756">
<amount>1</amount>
<operdate>20121126 03:57:10</operdate>
<purpose>test</purpose>
<pursefrom>Rxxx</pursefrom>
<wmidfrom>WMIDxxx</wmidfrom>
<capitallerflag>0</capitallerflag>
<enumflag>3</enumflag>
<IPAddress>95.28.75.19</IPAddress>
<telepat_phone/>
<telepat_paytype>null</telepat_paytype>
<paymer_number/>
<paymer_email/>
<paymer_type>null</paymer_type>
<cashier_number/>
<cashier_date/>
<cashier_amount>-1</cashier_amount>
<sdp_type/>
<sdp_phone/>
</operation>
<retval>0</retval>
<retdesc/>
</merchant.response>
```

Вот как, средствами php, получить значение amount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$xml = new DomDocument;
$xml -> ValidateOnParse = true;
$xml -> load('test.xml');
$amount = $xml -> getElementsByTagName('amount')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: @ViruSkin, проблема в том, что если ответ приходит с curl в формате xml, то неизвестно как быть. Никакие функции работы с xml не помогают.

Answer (score 1):

[SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.simplexml.php)

Answer (score 1):

[Вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/165300/php-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-xml-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0) пример.